# Matlab: How to return output from a function in a set()?

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, set, handles

I am now using `Matlab GUI` and have problem during accessing return values from a function which is set by set().

Situation:
I set the `windowMotionFcn` as below:

```
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@test);
```

Function 'test' can return 2 variables (named as var1 and var2).But I dont know how to store them...
I have searched in the Internet and could not find any way.

How should I write?

Thank you for your help and kind attention.

Comment: How do you want the data stored? Do you want to utilize it in another callback? Do you want to display it in the output panel? Do you want to save it to a file?

Comment: have you tried `set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', [@test])`, or `set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', {@test})` ?

Comment: Hi @excaza,

I want to store my variables like: 
[storeVar1 storeVar2] = test
    Thx a lot

Comment: Hi @JayInNyc , I tried your code before but it did not work. The {} is for passing input parameters to test function. Thank you for your nice help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is to **return** a value from the callback function. And regarding returning a value from a callback I am not sure that is possible. I found an old article from [matlab newsreader](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/258483). I think your problem could be similar.

However, if you have a matlab GUIDE GUI, there is a way to return a value from a gui. It is described in a matlab tutorial in [matlab central: advanced-getting-an-output-from-a-guide-gui](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/02/12/advanced-getting-an-output-from-a-guide-gui/). What you must do is to modify your `CloseRequestFcn` and your `OutputFcn`.

Another way, which should work is using global variables. A global varable exist in the global workspace. That means that it can be seen and accessed by every function in matlab. Global variables are in most cases not recommended, but if no other solution exists they may be necessary. Just make sure to document them, so that the next person to take over your code knows that they are there. Also make sure to select a good name for the globals, like `gblMyVar` so there can be no confusion that the variable is global.